# Memory location and allocation

Tags: opencl, gpgpu

Ex: To perform an algorithm on an array, we must use a buffer created with an array.
But with a Intel/AMD CPU, it use the DDR of the system like Global Memory.
Finally, the table is created twice. Is there a way to use the table already in memory without allocating buffer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can ***ask*** OpenCL to use the original memory area by setting the **CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR** flag when creating the buffer.

If the kernel is run on a CPU no memory copy will occur.

If run on a GPU a copy ***might*** occur if the OpenCL runtime thinks it's more suitable.

Answer (score 3):

The CPU has access to the machine's memory, but doesn't have access to the GPU's memory. Likewise, the GPU has access to its own memory, but not to the host machine's. This is the reason that you must transfer the information between those - they are two completely separate memory spaces.

As opposed to gpgpu, with OpenCL the kernel might run on the CPU itself, so no need to copy the buffer; but OpenCL still always requires you to explicitly transfer the memory, it's just that its implementation will ignore it if it's running on the host computer.

Comment: So the data are allocated twice on a OpenCL CPU platform and any trick exist to fix that ? 
In image processing, it's a big waste of performance.

Comment: @AlexPlacet I guess I wasn't clear enough... if you use OpenCL and your target device is the CPU, the data **won't** be allocated twice. If you use the exact same code on a GPU, it will.